# UDP tunnel over SSH : almost?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel, voip

I am trying to set up a UDP tunnel over SSH but it doesn't work.

Machine A is under Windows
Machine B is running Linux

I want to connect (voice over IP) from machine A to machine B via UDP with protocol SIP.

1. On machine A I did :
   socat.exe udp4-listen:5060,reuseaddr,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:10000
2. On machine B I did 
   socat tcp4-listen:10002,reuseaddr,fork UDP:127.0.0.1:5060
3. On machine A I did also :
   SSH tunnel from machine A, port 10000 to machine B port 10002

But it doesn't seem to work, at least according to a SIP VOIP phone I am trying to use ?

Any suggestion would be welcomed :-)

Comment: yes it's not a duplicate, I want to do the same but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you give us anything else beyond "it doesn't work".  Are you sure your SSH tunnel is setup correctly? What other tests have you run?  Can you try running the `socat` commands without the tunnel, just sending the output of one directly to the input of the other?

Comment: Also, please note some of the comments in the duplicate question, that this method can break the UDP stream, which might be happening too.  I found in my trials that it was a pretty fragile implementation and that a true VPN is a much more robust.

Comment: Why don't you just use OpenVPN? At this point, it is much less than a headache.

Comment: I cannot try to run the socat commands without the tunnel because I am not currently located on the network as machine B. But next week I will be able to try and keep you informed. When I say that it doesn't work the problem is that the VOIP phone is not giving much information, but I also tried udptrace.exe... For the SSH tunnel, yes it is correctly set up, I use many tunnels everyday, but i't the first time I try socat. My question was more about "is it correct to do as I did, is there any error in my commands ?"

Comment: ...and yes I saw your comment about the pretty fragile implementation. But for OpenVPN, I never saw a VPN working well, in my life, whether open or commercial, it's always very bugged. If it works it is also very fragile. Maybe I only had bad experience with it, and others use it everyday, but until now I consider VPN more as a myth ;)

Comment: But I will try OpenVPN anyway ;)